# Is there a way to use a Component to display detail of a blog post on click in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was trying to create a route that shows details "individual" of a blog post when someone clicks on a post on a blog website (Please keep in mind that the posts are stored in a Component rather than pages) -  as such:

```
Component
 |_ Posts.js
 |_ PostDetailsModal.js
```

On a regular page/route, I know how to display individual post by adding `bracket`  to the page names e.g: `/blog/[id].js`  but my challenge is how to use a Component to display each 'individual' blog post when someone clicks -  is there a way to accomplish that in nextJS app or is this only achievable through page routes?

I have tried to map through the array and pass props into the Modal, but they all returned `undefined`.

This is a sample code that displays a list of posts:

```
        <ul>
                  {currentItems <= 0 ? (
                    <span>
                      You have no recent activity
                    </span>
                  ) : currentItems.length > 0 ? (
                    currentItems.map((activity) => {
                      const {
                        id,
                        user_id,
                        description,
                        amount,
                        platform,
                        my_name,
                        updateAt,
                        date,
                        followers,
                      } = activity;
                      return (
                        <>
                          <li key={id}>
                            <span>
                              <span>                           
                                <span>
                                  {user_id ? (
                                    <span>
                                      {description}
                                    </span>
                                  ) : null}
                                  <span>
                                    <span>
                                      {amount}
                                    </span>{" "}
                                  </span>
                                  <span>
                                    {month[updateAt]}&nbsp;
                                    {date}
                                  </span>
                                </span>
                              </span>
                             
                            </span>
                            <button                         
                              type="button"
                              onClick=""
                            >
                              Check Status
                            </button>
                          </li> 
                           <ActivityModal
                            id={id}
                            user_id={user_id}
                            amount={amount}
                            platform={platform}
                            my_name={my_name}
                            followers={followers}
                          />               
                        </>
                      );
                    })
                  ) : null}
                </ul>
```

Any and all tips would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a local state in your page component, containing the ID of the post to display. If the flag is defined, then you display the modal:

```js
const [displayedPostId, setDisplayedPostId] = useState(null);

// ...
return (
  <div>
    // ...
    {currentItems.map((activity) => {
      const { id } = activity;
      return (
        // ...
        <button onClick={() => setDisplayedPostId(id)}>Show post</button>
      );
    })}

    // ...

    {displayedPostId !== null && (
      <PostDetailsModal
        postId={displayedPostId}
        onClose={() => setDisplayedPostId(null)}
        />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Note that this has little to do with Next.js, and it’s more a common React pattern :)